# How can I use struct efficiently in my quiz?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple quiz with struct. But my program here is very repetitive. How can I modify it and make it more efficient? Especially to check if the answers are correct I do not want to declare a separate variable and store it as `int correct`. Thank You.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Quiz{
    string question;
    string answers[3];
};

struct Quiz2{
    string question2;
    string answers2[3];
};

int correct;



int main()
{
    Quiz Question;
    Question.question = "What is the smallest county?";
    cout << Question.question << endl;
    
    Question.answers[0] = "1. USA";
    cout << Question.answers[0] << endl;
    
    Question.answers[1] = "2. India";
    cout << Question.answers[1] << endl;
    
    Question.answers[2] = "3. Vatican City";
    cout << Question.answers[2] << endl;
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Choose 1-3: ";
    cin >> correct;
    
    if(correct == 3)
        cout << "Correct!";
    else
        cout << "Incorrect!";
        
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
 // Question 2
        
    Quiz2 Question2;
    Question2.question2 = "What is the biggest animal in the world?";
    cout << Question2.question2 << endl;
    
    Question2.answers2[0] = "1. Elephant";
    cout << Question2.answers2[0] << endl;
    
    Question2.answers2[1] = "2. Blue Whale";
    cout << Question2.answers2[1] << endl;
    
    Question2.answers2[2] = "3. Great white shark";
    cout << Question2.answers2[2] << endl;
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Choose 1-3: ";
    cin >> correct;
    
    if(correct == 2)
        cout << "Correct!";
    else
        cout << "Incorrect!";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that `struct` is needed to define a "template"/"scheme" of an object. You certainly don't need a separate struct for every question

Comment: In your original code, you could remove all the uses of you `Quiz` and `Quiz2` structs, as you assign a single member then immediately output it's value, and never use it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's as much as non-repetitive as I can imagine after a few minutes of thinking. Maybe it can become smaller, but for my taste this looks alright.

You basically rely on `std::vector` class, instead of a typical array, because vectors can be of dynamic size. This allows us to use only one struct, but make as many answers as we want (3, 5, 10, whatever). We then create the whole quiz as another vector of questions. We're only left with printing to the console - for that we use loops, as our quiz structure is very simple and self-repetitive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Question{
    string question;
    int correct_idx;
    vector<string> answers;

    Question(string question, int correct_idx, vector<string> answers)
       :question(question), correct_idx(correct_idx), answers(answers)
    {}   
};


int main()
{
    vector<Question> whole_quiz = {
        Question{
           "What is the smallest country?", 
           2, // indexes start from 0, e.g. 0, 1, 2. So 2 is correct
           {"USA", "India", "Vatican City"}
        },
        Question{
           "What is the biggest animal in the world?", 
           1,
           {"Elephant", "Blue Whale", "Great white shark"}
        },
    };
    for(auto question : whole_quiz) {
        cout << question.question << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < question.answers.size(); ++i) {
            cout << i+1 << ". " << question.answers[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Choose 1-" << question.answers.size() << endl << endl;
        int guess;
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess-1 == question.correct_idx) {
            cout << "Correct!" << endl << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Incorrect!" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a more complicated, but also a more fun solution. Have a huge list of answers, like 100, or 1000, or as many as you like. Then in your struct have a `std::string` question, and `std::vector<int>` possible answers that are indexes in the huge list. First answer in the list is the correct one. So when you ask a question you pick first index, and three more indexes at random, and you shuffle them up, and present this to the user. The quiz will be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` acts as a **template**, not a single variable. so there's no need to create 2 different `struct`. Also, a `correct` variable can be added to the struct for ease of checking.

Code (I split it into different functions for clearer understanding):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct quiz
{
    int correct;
    string question;
    vector<string> answers;

};

vector<quiz> questionsToAsk;

void addNewQuestion(string ques, vector<string>ans, int cor)
{
    quiz q1;
    q1.question = ques;
    q1.answers = ans;
    q1.correct  = cor;
    questionsToAsk.push_back(q1);
}

void displayQuestion(int idx)
{
    quiz cur = questionsToAsk[idx];
    cout << cur.question << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < cur.answers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << cur.answers[i] << '\n';
    }
    cout << "Choose 1-3: "; int inp; cin >> inp;
    if (inp ==  cur.correct) {cout << "Correct";} else {cout << "Incorrect";} cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> ans1({"1. USA", "2. India", "3. Vatican City"});
    vector<string> ans2({"1. Elephant", "2. Blue Whale", "3. Great white shark"});

    addNewQuestion("What is the smallest county?", ans1, 3);
    addNewQuestion("What is the biggest animal in the world?", ans2, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < questionsToAsk.size(); i++)
    {
        displayQuestion(i);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
What is the smallest county?
1. USA
2. India
3. Vatican City
Choose 1-3: 1
Incorrect
What is the biggest animal in the world?
1. Elephant
2. Blue Whale
3. Great white shark
Choose 1-3: 2
Correct
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template like

```
<typename T = int>
T get_answer(std::istream& in) {
    T res;
    in >> res;
    return res;
}
...
if(get_answer(std::cin) == 3)
    cout << "Correct!";
else
    cout << "Incorrect!";
```

You can also overload `operator<<`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T = int>
T get_answer(std::istream& in) {
    T res;
    in >> res;
    return res;
}

class Quiz{
  public:
    Quiz(const std::string& q, const std::string& a1, const std::string& a2, const std::string& a3, unsigned correct)
      : question(q), answers{a1, a2, a3}{
        CheckAnswer(correct);
      }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Quiz& quiz) {
        os << quiz.question << "\n";
        unsigned i = 1;
        for (const auto & answer : quiz.answers) {
            os << i++ << ". " << answer << "\n";
        }
        os << "\n";
        return os;
    }
    void CheckAnswer(unsigned correct) {
        std::cout << *this << "Choose 1-3: ";
        if(get_answer(std::cin) == correct)
            std::cout << "Correct!";
        else
            std::cout << "Incorrect!";
 
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  private:
    std::string question;
    std::string answers[3];
};

int main()
{
    Quiz Question("What is the smallest county?", "USA", "India", "Vatican City", 3);
    
 // Question 2
        
    Quiz Question2("What is the biggest animal in the world?", "Elephant", "Blue Whale", "Great white shark", 2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you can do is define the `correct` variable in the struct itself. You can use a loop for decreasing the repetitiveness but obviously the question and the answers will have to be stored, it cannot be simplified further.